# XML transformer - set OutputKeys.DOCTYPE_SYSTEM with complex external entity declaration: cannot remove final double quotation

Tags: java, xml

In my transformer, I have this configuration:

```
trans.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.DOCTYPE_SYSTEM, "MLP_SVC_RESULT_320.DTD [<!ENTITY % extension SYSTEM \"company_mlp320_slia_extension.dtd\"> %extension;]");
```

Which gives me error:

```
[Fatal Error] :1:121: The document type declaration for root element type "svc_result" must end with '>'.
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: xxx; The document type declaration for root element type "svc_result" must end with '>'.
```

Because it adds an additional `"` at the end of my DOCTYPE line:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><!DOCTYPE svc_result SYSTEM "MLP_SVC_RESULT_320.DTD [<!ENTITY % extension SYSTEM "company_mlp320_slia_extension.dtd"> %extension;]">
```

Notice the last `"`, it cannot be there; the correct XML does not contain it.

But I have no clue how to remove it with correct configuration.

One example of correct XML:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<!DOCTYPE svc_result SYSTEM "MLP_SVC_RESULT_320.DTD" [<!ENTITY % extension SYSTEM "company_mlp320_slia_extension.dtd"> %extension;]>
<svc_result ver="3.2.0">
    <slia ver="3.0.0">
        <pos>
            <msid type="MSISDN" enc="ASC">200853000105614</msid>
            <gsm_net_param>
                <cgi>
                    <mcc>100</mcc>
                    <mnc>01</mnc>
                    <lac>2222</lac>
                    <cellid>10002</cellid>
                </cgi>
                <neid>
                    <vmscid>
                        <vmscno>00004946000</vmscno>
                    </vmscid>
                    <vlrid>
                        <vlrno>99994946000</vlrno>
                    </vlrid>
                </neid>
            </gsm_net_param>
        </pos>
        <company_mlp320_slia>
            <company_netinfo>
                <company_ms_netinfo type="CGI">
                    <msid type="MSISDN" enc="ASC">200853000105614</msid>
                    <time utc_off="+0200">20210521170211</time>
                </company_ms_netinfo>
            </company_netinfo>
        </company_mlp320_slia>
    </slia>
</svc_result>
```

Full code:

```
    private String transformToString(Document document) {
        if (document == null) {
            return null;
        }
        document.setXmlStandalone(true); // make document to be standalone, so we can avoid outputing standalone="no" in first line
        TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer trans;
        try {
            trans = tf.newTransformer();
            trans.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "no"); // no extra indent; file already has intent of 4
            trans.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.DOCTYPE_SYSTEM, "MLP_SVC_RESULT_320.DTD [<!ENTITY % extension SYSTEM \"company_mlp320_slia_extension.dtd\"> %extension;]");
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            trans.transform(new DOMSource(document), new StreamResult(sw));
            // Spaces between tags are considered as text node, so when outputing we need to remove the extra empty lines
            return sw.toString().replaceAll("\\n\\s*\\n", "\n");
        } catch (TransformerException e) {
            LOG.error("Cannot transform response document to String. ", e);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The serialization property DOCTYPE_SYSTEM is for outputting the system ID in the Doctype declaration. You're trying to abuse it to inject an entire DTD, and the processor isn't letting you get away with it.

XSLT has no built in mechanism for injecting a DTD into the serialized output. Unless you count `disable-output-escaping`, which is a hack but may solve the problem.

Saxon (PE and higher) has an extension instruction `saxon:doctype` to get around this limitation (though it's not a perfect solution, it has limitations of its own).

Comment: Let me ignore this line in the output for now... and mark it as TODO, as it is only for simulation. I guess it may work without it. Thanks anyway, I think the answer is valid and not really many ppl can post a solution.

Comment: At last I convert the XML to String and use `String.replace()` to add this line manually.